Automate PowerBI - "Rename for this visual" on multiple visuals/pages?
In PowerBI, I have a table with lots of fields (of course).  Some are called "City Address", "Values", "Dollars".
I am using these as a row/column in some tables, on multiple pages.  Is there a way I can write a macro/automate the renaming of the fields, so I don't have to manually click each one, and then do "Rename for this visual"?
Basically, I'd like it to loop through all fields in all visuals, and replace "City Address" with "Address".  The "Dollars" gets Summed, so becomes "Sum of Dollars", so I'd like that to just be "$ Dollars", etc.

The PBIP format is probably your best bet. It effectively exports the design of a PBIX file out into a folder text files in json format, that you can (carefully) edit. Using a tool like Visual Studio Code you can then make mass file edits, once you zero in on what you need to change.
Re-open the PBIP file using Power BI Desktop to review your changes.  Once I have finished, I would Save As PBIX before continuing, as the PBIP format is still in Preview rn.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/projects/projects-overview
But personally I would rename the fields in the semantic model to avoid all of that, and avoid manual renames. I would replace "Sum of X" for numeric fields with a measure, even if that just contains:
$ X = SUM ( MyTable[X] )

